# I am not able to pass a query parameter to mongoexport

Tags: json, mongodb, command-line, mongoexport

when I try export from MongoDB only specific record  (specified by query `{'Deleted':false}`) I got mentioned error:

`mongoexport -d=AAA-Master -c='CMD.File' -q="{'Deleted':false}" --out cnt_file.json`

`2023-02-27T12:42:47.424+0100    connected to: mongodb://localhost/`

`2023-02-27T12:42:47.435+0100    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input`

Platform is Windows 11, MongoDB version 4.4.18.

I also tried it this way `-q='{"Deleted":false}'` - with the same result.

Why?
According to the documentation seems be all correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The way how write the query is:
`-q="{\"Name\":\"0100\",\"Deleted\":false}"`

Here is more:
[Mongodump –query not able to filter using timestamp](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodump-query-not-able-to-filter-using-timestamp/2113)